# Преобразовать String из 0 и 1 в byte

Tags: java, byte

Есть переменная типа String, которой присвоена строка, состоящая из восьми нулей и единиц (например, "01011010"). Нужно присвоить переменной типа byte, значение идентичное двоичному числу, указанному в значении строки String, т.е.:

```
String str = "01011010";
byte b = 01011010;
```

Как это сделать (без сторонних библиотек)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = "01011010";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(str, 2);
```